# How do I split a “data.frame” type column while preserving other column types?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` where one of the columns `user` is itself a `data.frame`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  user = data.frame(
    id = numeric(),
    name = character()
  ),
  color = character()
)

df[nrow(df)+1,] <- c(1,"joe","green")
```

How do I split the `user` column into the `id` and `name` columns so that `df` has the `id` and `name` columns instead of the `user` column, while keeping the `color` column?

Comment: For some reason, your examples are not generating the nested data.frame.  Can you use `dput`?

Comment: `dput(df)` output: `structure(list(user.id = "1", user.name = "joe", color = "green"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")`

Comment: The dput, shows 3 columns `str(df)
'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:$ user.id  : chr "1"
 $ user.name: chr "joe"
 $ bean     : chr "black"`

Comment: `user` is not a dataframe for the example you have shared nor in the `dput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.frame` structure showed in the OP's post is not reproducible.  So, constructed a `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
            mutate(user = list(user)) %>%
            unnest_wider(c(user)) 

str(df1)
#tibble [1 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ id   : num 1
# $ name : chr "joe"
# $ color: chr "green"
```

---

NOTE: when we adding a new row with assignment, if we choose a vector (`c(...)`), there is a limitation in having different types as `vector` allows only a single type.  Instead use a `list`

#### data

```
df <- tibble(user = tibble(id = 1, name = "joe"), color = "green")
```